# Connecting FreeNAS 8 to Mac OS X Lion LDAP Server

Tags: ldap, mac-osx-server, truenas, opendirectory

I currently have Mac OS X Lion Server running from a MacMini and want to use it purely as an LDAP server for authentication for FreeNAS 8. I have FreeNAS setup and running on a VM, all features working correctly and as expected however I cannot connect to my LDAP server (MacMini).

Error message;

```
**Nss_ldap: could not search LDAP server – server is unavailable**
```

For LDAP service settings in FreeNAS, I know my Hostname and Base DN are correct (exact copies of what I set originally and ones that are shown in server:open directory overview) however I am unsure what to enter for Root bind DN, password and Suffix’s. I have researched into where I can find these out and other than following the FreeNAS examples it appears there is a way to find out within the Server Workgroup Manager specific to my settings – however this function is unavailable to me and cannot be ‘ticked’ to view for some strange reason.

Some forums explain how Root bind DN should be `uid=admin, dc=…` and others `cn=admin, dc=…` – I’m rather confused and would appreciate your help or advice with this.

Comment: Did you manage to connect to the LDAP in the end?

Comment: Hi freddy, no I didn't, I actually reorganised a few things and used FreeNAS for user accounts and storage for the time being until I sorted a long term solution. Although, I'm no longer working there so not my problem anymore!

Answer (score 1):

I'm running FreeNAS 8.3.x, OD Master server runs on Mac OS Server 10.7.4 and I was able to get these working together as follows.

- Using the FreeNAS web interface go to Services > LDAP
- I used "host.domain.com" for the Hostname field where the Hostname is that of my OD Master.
- Set the Base DN to "dc=host,dc=domain,dc=com", e.g.
- I set my Root bind DN to "uid=mydiradmin,cn=users,dc=host,dc=domain,dc=com"
- I entered my Directory Admin password in and chose md5 for password encryption
- Set the Group Suffix to "cn=groups"
- Left the "Password Suffix" blank
- Set "Machine Suffix" to "cn=machines"
- I left encryption off, not currently requiring it due to having some devices on the network not work well with it on.

To test I setup an AFP share with allowing my group for all staff and I was able to authenticate without any issues.  I got a good quick test that I used was looking in my NFS share properties for "Map root user" and/or "Map root group" and when I got it working I was able to see my users and groups in the list.